# Custom ListPickerPage.xaml doesnot populate Items in fullmode popup

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have a requirement where I need to set the background of the `FullMode` popup of the `ListPicker` control in Windows phone 7. So, I took the `ListPickerPage.xaml file` from Silverlight toolkit, and customized it in my project. Now when I run the project, the `ListPicker` opens up the `FullMode` page with a white background but, no items in it. What could be the possible problem?

Comment: Could it be that the foreground text of your items is also white? (in case of the dark theme set on your phone)

Comment: I checked my code. Foreground is set properly. Somehow, the Items list in PickerPage is not getting set proeprly. I did a workaround by manually setting the items list (transferring the list using Phone State variable). I can see the list now, but the selectedItem in listpicker doesnot get set.

Comment: It's difficult to guess more than the foreground text property issue. If possible, share some code with us.